# C# re-throwing exception outside of scope

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I am fully aware that what I am about to ask is not good practice... but:

Let's say I have a class containing a function that I want to always return a value, but store any exceptions that might occur for later processing. Something Like:

```
public Exception _error { get; set; }

public bool IsValid()
{
    try
    {
        //do something here to cause exception                

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _error = ex;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now that I have stored the exception, is it at all possible to throw the exception from an outside method while maintaining both the original stack trace and exception type?

```
throw _error; //lose stack trace

throw new Exception("", _error) //lose type
```

Thanks for looking or answering.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to some additional points, I realize that the below idea only takes away information and doesn't really add or simplify the situation. Thanks again to everyone.

<strike>After pondering Pieter's answer and comments, I'm now wondering if making a wrapper Exception class like the below could be a partial solution. This overrides as much of the exception as possible to make the New exception look like its innerexception, including the stacktrace.. dirty I know, but interesting:</strike>

```
public class ExceptionWrapper : Exception
{
    private Exception _innerException;

    public ExceptionWrapper(Exception ex) : base("", ex)
    {
        _innerException = ex;
        this.Source = ex.Source;
        this.HelpLink = ex.HelpLink;
    }

    public override string StackTrace
    {
        get
        {
            return _innerException.StackTrace;
        }
    }

    public override System.Collections.IDictionary Data
    {
        get
        {
            return _innerException.Data;
        }
    }

    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return _innerException.Message;
        }
    }

    public new Exception InnerException
    {
        get
        {
            return _innerException.InnerException;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although you probably realise, please **never** throw `System.Exception`

Comment: Ha, yeah I would not do that in code, it was just a quick example, but I appreciate you pointing that out!

Comment: @Matthew There is nothing wrong with throwing "Exception". I believe you are incorrectly referring to the best of practice of never *catching* "Exception".

Comment: Actually I'm referring to the lack of context driven by simply throwing `Exception`.  Throwing `Exception` means to get any real detail out of the exception, you need to inspect the message, data or any internal exceptions. By throwing an appropriate exception, e.g. an `ArgumentException`, or an `InvalidOperationException` gives context to why the exception was thrown.

Comment: @Matthew **Tip** If you wish to reply to other user's comments, please include their @username or they will not be notified, so may never read your response.

Comment: Here's another thing that Java can do that .NET cannot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, this is not possible.**

However, you normally solve this is by wrapping the exception in a new exception:

```
throw new MyException("Wrapper", _error);
```

This does maintain the stack trace of `_error`, but you do get a new exception. Your solution in your second example is the correct way of handling these cases.

Comment: +1 for making it your own exception type. This gives you context for the wrapped exception, so you are not really "losing" the type.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply @Pieter, and good clarification @unholysampler. That makes sense, but still means that higher level handlers have to know about the custom exception type. Appreciate it.

Comment: What you normally do, in case this applies to some library or framework, is that you create a single exception for this. E.g., NHibernate has NHibernateException which it uses for almost all its exceptions.

Comment: @Pieter, @unholysampler, thanks for the information. I have added an Edit, with a new thought in regard to a Wrapper exception class... It's not a clean solution but at least looks reasonable in a log file... what do you think?

Comment: @ach - To be honest: no, not really. What I normally do in log files is that when I log a stack trace, I **always** log the stack trace of the exception and **all** inner exceptions. This way you always have all information available in the logs. This is specifically a good idea because there are many cases where libraries (or e.g. the .NET framework) uses wrapped exceptions, and you then also support those cases.

Comment: @Pieter - That's a very good point, I was actually just about edit again and strike out that thought. Especially since it doesn't really add anything, only takes away info. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider using reflection to create a wrapper exception of the correct type ([Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)) and calling the constructor that will accept the inner exception you have stored.

For example:

```
[Test]
public void test()
{
    Exception ex = new ArgumentNullException();

    Exception wrapped = (Exception)Activator.
        CreateInstance(ex.GetType(), "wrapped", ex);

    Type expectedType = typeof(ArgumentNullException);

    Assert.IsInstanceOf(expectedType, wrapped, "Is ArgumentNullException.");

    Assert.AreEqual(ex, wrapped.InnerException, "Exception is wrapped.");
}
```

**Update**

In order to mitigate the constructor issue, you could consider using the default constructor (should be there for an exception that follows design guidelines, but not mandatory) and then patching up the new instance by setting its fields via reflection.

I agree the approach is highly "**meh**" it's more an exploration of an idea. I wouldn't recommend it.

The exception design guidelines require a default constructor, so this sort of behaviour may go on in the framework somewhere anyway. Perhaps for some sort of icky serialization\deserialization of exceptions across some sort of communications boundary?

Comment: I was thinking about something like this, but it depends too highly on the available constructors and is not very lightweight... still something to think about. Thanks.

Comment: @ach Correct, there is an issue with availability of constructors to contend with. I wouldn't be too concerned with the light-weight aspect of it. You are already in an exceptional situation so lots of expensive stack walking etc has already been carried out. You're not exactly on a golden path re. performance at this stage.

Comment: I don't like using reflection to monkey with the internals of classes you don't control.  Because things like InnerException are properties, there's no way that outside code can set them and know that it will work.  The best way to deal with things is by creating a new exception type to wrap the existing exception.  The lack of a useful exception hierarchy makes it difficult to do anything better.

Comment: @supercat See my evaluation of method: **meh**. Plus in the original question the OP discussed preserving the original exception type if possible - wrapping is not a solution to this.

Comment: @chibacity: My dislike would be a bit stronger than "meh".  Plus, even if you create your new exception instance I'm not at all clear how you're going to throw it while preserving the original stack trace.  The original poster's idea of wrapping the exception object with one whose own StackTrace property would report as the original object's would take care of the stack trace issue, but that fundamentally won't work if you're creating a new exception type.  If the stack trace doesn't matter, just throw the original exception.

Comment: @supercat Ok, **meh++** - i think that's more than 'highly **meh**' + 'I wouldn't recommend it'? The proposal is to create an exception of the correct type using reflection, then set it's inner exception with the original exception - the inner exception has the original stack trace. It's basically exception wrapping but maintaining the correct exception type.

Comment: @chibacity: Oh, I see I miseed the "ex" parameter in the Activator.CreateInstance, which you're hoping will be interpreted as an InnerException property.  That's probably a pretty safe assumption assuming the exception in question implements the proper constructor.  You may need to wrap the Activator.CreateInstance in an exception, though, in case you get an exception which for whatever reason lacks that constructor.

Comment: @supercat And if you read my update you'll see I propose using the default constructor to avoid the ctor issue, and blasting the values in via private fields. All horrible I know, although you could see it as a low-level clone where you use reflection to iterate over the fields of one instance and blast them into the other. All highly icky I know :)

Comment: @chibacity: I think I'm more comfortable with trying the proper constructor first than with using reflection to blast the field.  If the exception has a constructor with Message and InnerException parameters, that should create a valid instance of that exception.  If the constructor doesn't exist, the omission may well have been because a valid instance of that particular exception requires some additional data (e.g. field "InnerExceptions" may be expected to hold a List<Exception>, and whatever catches the exception may die with a NullReferenceException if it doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that .net-4.5 added a new API for capturing stack/info about exceptions and rethrowing them in different contexts. This is called [`ExceptionDispatchInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.exceptionservices.exceptiondispatchinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is useful if you find yourself needing more control over running tasks indirectly, like if you do manual thread management for jobs or `Task` does not exactly fit your needs. In your example, it should look like this:

```
public ExceptionDispatchInfo _error { get; private set; }

public bool IsValid()
{
    try
    {
        //do something here to cause exception                

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _error = ExceptionDispatchInfo.Capture(ex);
        return false;
    }
}

/// <summary>Throw underlying exception if invalid.</summary>
public void AssertWasValid() => _error?.Throw();
```

Now, it doesn’t preserve the original caller. The displayed stack trace shows the calls from the original `try` block into the code in there, a statement breaking the original and new parts of the stack, and then the calls into `ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()` itself as the new part of the shown stack. This seems similar to how traces with `async` code look. If you care about the original caller, seems this won’t work. But if you care about getting the line/method that threw the exception, this should be sufficient.